# Can Xcode make a .exe file?

Tags: xcode, plist, executable

I need to build a small program in Xcode that will edit a safari file on a PC.
The file is 'Extensions.plist' in '...\Apple Computer\Safari\Extensions' folder.

Im on a PC, and since 'Extensions.plist' is in Xcode,
I need to write the code on a Mac with Xcode and generate a .exe file from it.
Then from a NSIS script, I want to call this .exe file to do the changes i need to the Extensions.plist file.

My question is,
Is it possible to output a .exe file from Xcode on mac that will run on a PC ?

Thanks.

Comment: No, but you don't need to use Xcode. A .plist file is a just an XML-like text file and so you can edit it with pretty much anything.

Comment: Why would anyone upvote this?

Comment: hey man you know what is a plist file?

Comment: @Saurabh a plist file is a 'property list' file. In my case, it stores all information about the extensions actually installed in the safari browser

Comment: I totally agree that this should be XML. But, since it totally failed reading it with a xml parser. It seem that any changes in plist must be done in Xcode as said here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#Property_List_Editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Im on a PC, and since 'Extensions.plist' is in Xcode, I need to write the code on a Mac with Xcode

No, why? What do you mean by “'Extensions.plist' is in Xcode”? The plist file is simply an XML file. Xcode is an IDE. Where is the connection here?

To answer your question: Xcode doesn’t normally allow generating exe files. However, you *can* generate .NET exe files on a mac by using the Mono C# compiler. You can theoretically also call this compiler from within Xcode by configuring an own project type for C# projects (“external build system”). But there is no advantage in doing this in your case.

Comment: I tried parsing the file with xml parser but failed. Then i saw this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#Property_List_Editor

Comment: @developerGuile How does the fact that Xcode contains a plist editor help you in the slightest when you try to write an application for modifying the lists yourself? Try again parsing the plist as XML. This is the way to go.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph The editor has nothing to do, i was refering to ' all editing of plist files must be done within Xcode itself.' If the file is in XML, i should be able to open it with any editor. right ? but when i do, i see this: bplist00Ó _Available UpdatesWVersion_Installed ExtensionsÒ_Last Update Check Time\Updates List#A³iÇ¼gJ€ ¡Ó _Bundle Directory NameWEnabled_Archive File Name_Cloudy.safariextension _Cloudy.safariextz#+BG`mvwy{‚š¢¶ÏÐ

Comment: @developerGuile Duh. That’s the new binary plist format. Didn’t know that until now. But this article could help you: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050430105126392 and http://explanatorygap.net/2009/10/30/apple-have-documented-the-binary-plist-format/

Comment: I'll keep trying with different xml parser, never knows. But if anyone as safari browser installed on their pc, can u please try opening 'Extensions.plist' located in C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Safari\Extensions to confirm i am not crazy and it is not XML.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph OMG, thank you man. You got it. I'll use plutil to convert from binary to XML, make the changes and convert back to from XML to binary.

Comment: @developerGuile ;-) Glad I could help even though I completely misunderstood your problem initially.